# Declare a whole example group pending at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I think there was a command to declare a whole example group in rspec (rails) to be pending
I believe it was something like `before {pending}`, but I cannot find it any more.
Does anybody know how you can achieve this?

```
        context "Group1" do
            before { pending }
            it "example1" do
            end
            it "example2" do
            end
            it "example3" do
            end
        end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple replace descibe or context with pending

```
    pending "Group1" do
        before { pending }
        it "example1" do
        end
        it "example2" do
        end
        it "example3" do
        end
    end
```

Comment: nice, and always easier than you think :) (I mark your answer correct because you were earlier and it is basically correct although one would still have to clean "before {pending}" away)

Answer (score 1):

```
    pending "Group1" do
        it "example1" do
        end
        it "example2" do
        end
        it "example3" do
        end
    end
```